# Xamarin forms many errors from the beginning

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

After Xamarin installation in VS 2017 and after creating a cross-platform project in app.xaml.cs I have ten errors and nine warnings from the begginning (without doing anything). I did already a search and I find a solution to update xamarin forms to latest version but xamarin form has the latest version 2.5.0.28

The errors and warnings I get:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   App1.Android    C:\Users\vtsou_000\source\repos\App1\App1\App1\App.xaml.cs  6   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Application' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   App1.Android, App1.iOS  C:\Users\vtsou_000\source\repos\App1\App1\App1\App.xaml.cs  10  Active
Error   CS0115  'App.OnStart()': no suitable method found to override   App1.Android, App1.iOS  C:\Users\vtsou_000\source\repos\App1\App1\App1\App.xaml.cs  19  Active
Error   CS0115  'App.OnSleep()': no suitable method found to override   App1.Android, App1.iOS  C:\Users\vtsou_000\source\repos\App1\App1\App1\App.xaml.cs  24  Active
Error   CS0115  'App.OnResume()': no suitable method found to override  App1.Android, App1.iOS  C:\Users\vtsou_000\source\repos\App1\App1\App1\App.xaml.cs  29  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   App1.iOS    C:\Users\vtsou_000\source\repos\App1\App1\App1\App.xaml.cs  6   Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context    App1.Android, App1.iOS  C:\Users\vtsou_000\source\repos\App1\App1\App1\App.xaml.cs  14  Active
Error   CS0118  'MainPage' is a type but is used like a variable    App1.Android, App1.iOS  C:\Users\vtsou_000\source\repos\App1\App1\App1\App.xaml.cs  16  Active
Error       The type 'Application' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. App1.iOS    C:\Users\vtsou_000\source\repos\App1\App1\App1\App.xaml 2   
Error       The attachable property 'Resources' was not found in type 'Application'.    App1.iOS    C:\Users\vtsou_000\source\repos\App1\App1\App1\App.xaml 5   
Warning     No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.    App1.Android    C:\Users\vtsou_000\source\repos\App1\App1\App1.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  2   
Warning     Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.  App1.Android    C:\Users\vtsou_000\source\repos\App1\App1\App1.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  2   
Warning     No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.  App1.Android    C:\Users\vtsou_000\source\repos\App1\App1\App1.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  2   
Warning     No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'. App1.Android    C:\Users\vtsou_000\source\repos\App1\App1\App1.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  2   
Warning     No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'. App1.Android    C:\Users\vtsou_000\source\repos\App1\App1\App1.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  2   
Warning     No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.  App1.Android    C:\Users\vtsou_000\source\repos\App1\App1\App1.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  3   
Warning     No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.  App1.Android    C:\Users\vtsou_000\source\repos\App1\App1\App1.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  4   
Warning     No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionModeOverlay'.  App1.Android    C:\Users\vtsou_000\source\repos\App1\App1\App1.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  4   
Warning     Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog'. App1.Android    C:\Users\vtsou_000\source\repos\App1\App1\App1.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml  4
```

I am a new developer in Xamarin so I don't know what to do.

After restarting VS 2017 the old errors are gone but I still get new errors:

```
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_efe5e5bc\Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains adb in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_efe5e5bc\Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
    Path contains ndk-stack in \. (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_efe5e5bc\Android\JavaSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131).
[I:]:                     Found Xamarin.Android 8.2.0.15
[I:]:                     Found Android SDK. API levels: 25, 26
[I:]:                     Found Xamarin.Android 8.2.0.15
[I:sdk]:                  Runtime path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android
[I:sdk]:                  Framework path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0
[I:]:                     Tracking android devices started
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: 
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 0 devices
[D:]:                     live player watcher: got device list from live player with 1 devices
[D:]:                     Tracking avd started
[D:]:                     avd watcher *.ini path: 'C:\Users\vtsou_000\.android\avd'
[D:]:                     avd watcher: got device list from avd with 5 devices
[E:]:                     an error occurred loading avd `Android_Accelerated_Nougat`, the system image does not exists
[E:]:                     an error occurred loading avd `Android_ARM_Nougat`, the system image does not exists
[E:]:                     an error occurred loading avd `Nexus_5_API_24`, the system image does not exists
[E:]:                     an error occurred loading avd `Nexus_5_API_25`, the system image does not exists
```

and one more as an error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0103  The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context    App1.Android, App1.iOS  C:\Users\vtsou_000\source\repos\App1\App1\App1\App.xaml.cs  14  Active
```

Comment: Close and reopen the solution and perform a Clean All / Build All

Comment: That's do the job but I get new errors. Shall I put them in my question?

Comment: Sure, add them your question as an update after the original errors

Comment: Try restoring your nuget packages

Comment: I tried but nothing. Also after that I re-installed the xamarin and I had the same issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many attempts I figure out how to solve my question:

Deleting files from bin and obj is completely unnecessary and my problems didn't disappear.

The first thing I do is to built the solution.

The second is to unload and reload the solution from android. After this I have no errors in my code.

In addition sdk tools are not set properly and emulator don't work properly. So you have to install them. 
The other thing is on all xaml files in order to share variables. Right click on properties and in built action set to content and after to Embedded resource again.

As I said too many errors from beginning. Microsoft developers must solve those issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps.

1.Close visual studio.

2.Delete Bin & Obj folders in Portable & android projects.

3.Open the Visual studio.

4.Clean the Solution.

5.Rebuild the solution.

Comment: Where are Bin and Obj Folders? Will be fixed the emulator? What do you mean android projects?, I used cross-platform projects

Comment: Bin & Obj folders are where your project is created. Exampple like this: E:\xamarin forms projects\ApiImplementation\ApiImplementation\ApiImplementation

Comment: I am still have problems though. That is one part of a solution.